# using array with cookie for form data

Tags: php, forms, containers

I'm using a form to post data and collect it with PHP by using individual cookies after some validation..

it takes too much time to do things with the data which gets extended for more and more forms... I was thinking about improving my code with loops, functions or arrays, offered to create a map array...

share your suggestion on how should I re-write my code for more data and multiple forms which get the data exported to documents..

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['send']))
// name
if(strlen($_POST['name']) < 2){
  echo "error - name is too short";
}
// other validations with elseif..
else {
  setcookie('001',$_POST['name']);
}


// age
if((isset($_POST['age']) && is_numeric($_POST['age']))){ 
 setcookie('002',$_POST['age']);
}
?>

<form method="post">
<input name="name" type="text"/>
<input name="age" type="number"/>
<input type=submit" name="send" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think should store it as a key val pair in [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php). You can infinitely add more key-val pairs without worrying much. Also it will be secure as the data won't be exposed in cookies.